# Получить день недели первого числа месяца

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать свой календарь.
Еесть Gridview, где я заполняю числами количеством зависимости от длинны месяца.
Вверху GridView идёт 
Пн Вт СР Чт Пт Сб Вс дни недели.
Мне нужно получить день недели первого числа текущего месяца,что бы выставить первое число по календарю.
Например , май 1 число это вторник.
Вот как получить см то 01.05.2018  - это вторник?
Но вводить не вручную, а программно.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Распишите подробнее что именно Вы хотите получить. Покажите пример кода, если возможно.

Comment: Вы задаете много вопросов, но не приняли еще ни одного ответа. Непонятно, помогаем ли мы вам или нет. Не надо так

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DayOfWeek dow = LocalDate.parse("01.05.2018",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")).getDayOfWeek();
System.out.println(dow); //TUESDAY
System.out.println(dow.getValue()); //2
```

Или через календарь:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/06/2018");
c.setTime(date);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
```

Только в последнем случае нужно учитывать, что 1 означает воскресение, а 7 субботу.

Comment: date = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(("01/"+c.get (c.MONTH)+1) +"/"+c.get(c.YEAR)) = полное решение